# Citation problem in latex

Tags: bibtex

I'm going to write citation in my paper.

The reference is Master Thesis and I got this output

[image]

Here is the code

```
@MastersThesis{Paper10,
  author    = "Hasan Fleyeh",
  title     = "Traffic and Road Sign Recognition",
  school    = "Napier University",
  %type     = "diploma thesis",
  %address  = "",
  year      = "2008",
  month    = "July",
  %note     = "",
   }
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using some specific bib style?

Comment: What would you like to fix?

Comment: @egreg, I guess that the position of the comma after title.

Comment: Do you use BibTeX or biblatex? If it's BibTeX, which bibliography style -- the argument of the command `\bibliographystyle{...}` -- do you employ?

Comment: Im using \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS} with BibTxtMng and I want that the year and the month can be appear..

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

The commented lines in your bibliography entry are the culprit of the observed behavior.

This is the contents of the `.blg` file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: IEEEtranS.bst
Database file #1: test.bib
You're missing a field name---line 5 of file test.bib
 :
 : %type     = "diploma thesis",
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
-- IEEEtranS.bst version 1.13 (2008/09/30) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
** Sorting version - not for normal IEEE work.
Warning--empty year in Paper10

Done.
(There was 1 error message)
```

As you can see from the log, BibTeX is skipping all fields after `school` so `year` and `month` get not printed.

So, the solution is to remove the commented lines in your bibliography entry (lines starting with `%` are not comments in a bibliography entry):

```
@MastersThesis{Paper10,
  author    = "Hasan Fleyeh",
  title     = "Traffic and Road Sign Recognition",
  school    = "Napier University",
  year      = "2008",
  month    = "July",
  }
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MastersThesis{Paper10,
  author    = "Hasan Fleyeh",
  title     = "Traffic and Road Sign Recognition",
  school    = "Napier University",
  year      = "2008",
  month    = "July",
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]