# Citation problem using Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

I want to cite a PhD dissertation in my paper. I am using `IEEEtrans` class along with `Bibtex` for bibliography. The following is my entry in the `.bib` file.

```
@phdthesis{author2012thesis,
  title={Dramatic Words: Full Title},
  author={LastName, FirstName},
  year={2012},
  howpublished = "\url{http://abc/thesis.pdf}"
  school={Some School, Some Dept., Some Country}
}
```

Upon compiling I get the following result.

[image: screenshot]

I dont know why it is not printing out the school name and the department name. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168415/citation-problem-in-latex) had a similar problem but I checked that I have no lines commented out in the `.bib` file. Can anyone help identifying the issue here.

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the `howpublished` line. There should be an error or warning message to this effect in the blg file. As BibTeX crashes at that point, none of the information in the `school` field is processed, which explains why it's not shown in the formatted entry.

Comment: Incidentally, in the IEEEtran bibliography style, the entry type `@phdthesis` will only process fields named `author`, `title`, `school`, `address`, `date`, `note`, and `url`. Hence, the contents of the `howpublished` field will *not* get processed by the IEEEtran style. I suggest you rename the field name to, say, `note`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for catching the mistake as well as suggesting a solution as I have to stay with IEEEtran style. Can you put your comments in form of an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I've posted the comments as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with the bib entry you've posted. First, there's a comma missing at the end of the field named `howpublished`; remember that BibTeX expects a comma as the delimiter between fields. Second, the `howpublished` field isn't recognized -- and hence isn't processed -- by the bibliography style `IEEEtran`. I suggest you rename the field to either `note` or `url`. (With the bib style `IEEEtr`, only `note` would work correctly.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{author2012thesis,
  title={Dramatic Words: Full Title},
  author={LastName, FirstName},
  year={2012},
  note = "\url{http://abc/thesis.pdf}",
  school={Some School, Some Dept., Some Country}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % choose bib style appropriately
\usepackage{url,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
Work to be cited: \cite{author2012thesis}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using `biblatex-ieee`: `biblatex` has a specific `url` field, which works just fine, after the missing comma has been added:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style = ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{url.bib}
@phdthesis{author2012thesis,
  title={Dramatic Words: Full Title},
  author={LastName, FirstName},
  year={2012},
  url={http://abc/thesis.pdf},
  school={Some School, Some Dept., Some Country}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{url.bib}

\begin{document}

test \cite{author2012thesis}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]